# Remove all duplicate files in subdirectories in main directory

Tags: command-line, directory, uniq, delete

I am new to Linux and was wondering how I would go about deleting all duplicates with same file name but only keep one original?

For example I have the following:

```
dir_new_001 = rdt.txt
dir_new_002 = rdt.txt
dir_new_003 = rdt.txt
```

I just want to do it in command line.

Comment: Have you tried using `uniq`? Example: `echo -e 'abc\nabc\nabc\nbcd\nbcd' | uniq` returns `abc` and `bcd`.

Comment: @PauloTomé No SIr I havent sorry I am new noobie to Linux so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Sorry Didn't read your question correctly. Your question is about removing duplicated files in a directory, not removing duplicated lines in a file.

Comment: Do you want to keep just one file by name randomly, or do you have a criteria for the files to keep?

Comment: @PauloTomé keep only one instance of the file

Comment: Have you considered using a tool like `fdupes`? See [fdupes – A Command Line Tool to Find and Delete Duplicate Files in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/fdupes-find-and-delete-duplicate-files-in-linux/)

Comment: Do you have a file with filenames or does your `dirname = filename` mean you have a directory called `dirname` containing a file called `filename`?

Answer (score 0):

**So, let me formulate how I understand the task.**

*We have a text file "file.txt" containing lines with 3 columns:*

```
directory = file
```

*the same named filescan be in different directories, and we have to generate lines to leave a file with the same name just once and remove the rest.
Right?*

**Input file "file.txt":**

```
dir_new_001 = rdt.txt
dir_new_002 = rdt.txt
dir_new_003 = rdt.txt

dir_new_001 = rdt2.txt
dir_new_002 = rdt2.txt

dir_new_001 = rdt3.txt
dir_new_003 = rdt3.txt
```

**One line code to execute (using /bin/sh or /bin/bash):**

```
for i in $(cat file.txt|awk '{print $3}'|sort|uniq); do F=$(grep " = $i$" file.txt|tail -n+2|awk '{print $1"/"$3}'|xargs); [ -n "${F}" ] && echo "rm -f ${F}"; done|sort
```

Results:

```
rm -f dir_new_002/rdt2.txt
rm -f dir_new_002/rdt.txt dir_new_003/rdt.txt
rm -f dir_new_003/rdt3.txt
```

If you want to remove files, you can always execute "rm" instead of printing it using "echo".

Comment: Thanks SIr but what about for all specific files extensions say `.avi`?

Comment: @n00bl1nux You should make sure that your question contains all relevant information.  If you start adding conditions into comments, most people will miss that, and if Yurko updates their answer, their answer is no longer answering the actual question as it was given.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the `fdupes` utility issue the following command:

```bsh
$ fdupes -rdN dir/

r - recursive
d - preserver first file, delete other dupes
N - run silently (no prompt)
```

See  [fdupes – A Command Line Tool to Find and Delete Duplicate Files in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/fdupes-find-and-delete-duplicate-files-in-linux/) for more details.